# Edit Bootstrap Nav Pill layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Shoestrap / Roots.io Bootstrap theme for WordPress and need to do some slight tweaking of the the Nav bar.

Essentially, I need to add a span around the link text and inside the actual `<a>` tag.

For example:

Default rendering:

```
<a href="">LINK TEXT</a>
```

I need to make it, thus:

```
<a href=""><span>LINK TEXT</span></a>
```

I can't find any template parts or functions that seem to render the pills, which I could physically edit to add in the span tags.

Where can I look in order to implement the extra markup?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those themes but it's likely being generated dynamically, so look for any `.php` files with functions that would generate those sections of the page. Looks for IDs you can search for, or something specific to those templates.

Comment: @helion3 Thanks for the response. Ive had a 'good' luck around the theme files but nothing seems to get down to the required level.

Comment: *good look -pardon the stupidity. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't a good fit for SO because only a tiny set of people having that particular theme's file set available can help. Obviously editing or overriding the template file is the best option, but this may also be a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Bw6jZ/

```
$('#someId a').each(function () {
    var contents = $('a').html();
    $(this).html('<span>' + contents + '</span>');
});
```

Comment: The theme is quite a popular one, so I imagine its more than a few people and I imagined there to be enough SO experts to help me out. Unfortunately it seems not.